# Spring: Injecting an external properties into java Configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I've got a spring boot application (1.3.1.RELEASE) and recently experienced a strange behavior when trying to inject a `@ConfigurationProperties` bean into my configuration. I'm not an expert in Spring, so my question is how can this behavior be explained?

So the setup is like that:

*MyApplication.java*:

```
package me.developer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(final String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(<..>, args);
    }

}
```

*SecurityProperties.java*:

```
package me.developer.document.security;

@Setter
@Getter
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security")
public class SecurityProperties {   
    private List<String> apiKeys = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

*SecurityConfiguration.java*

```
package me.developer.document;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SecurityProperties securityProperties;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        <..>
    }

}
```

When the application is started I get an error that Spring can't inject *SecurityConfiguration.securityProperties* because it knows nothing about *me.developer.document.security.SecurityProperties* bean.

**But** if I rename `SecurityProperties` to `SicurityProperties` (second letter "e" --> "i") - it works! Don't ask me how did I get to that, but I'm just curious how this behavior can be explained? I.e. from my perspective it should either work or not, but not depending of the bean name, etc...

**Update**:
I also works if I don't touch the class name but explicitly specify the bean name like that

```
package me.developer.document.security;

@Setter
@Getter
@Component("securityProperties.my")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "security")
public class SecurityProperties {   
    private List<String> apiKeys = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

And I don't provide any additional qualifiers during autowiring... Why is it happening?

Comment: the bean name must match the class name except it is named with lower case for the first letter. for example bean `securityProperties` matches class  `SecurityProperties`. you probably have some typo resulted in this behavior

Comment: Nope (
The problem is it works when class name doesn't match bean name. I.e. `private SicurityProperties securityProperties`.

Comment: do you have a xml file or property file

Comment: There's an `application.yml` with all the stuff needed. But even if wasn't there the problem is not in reading it, but in Spring not seeing the `@ConfigurationProperties` bean... unless it's renamed O_o

Comment: check your `application.yml` file, if you have configuration about `securityProperties`, you should make sure it is spelled right. there is a sequence in Spring to look for files and certain property overwrite can happen.

Comment: It's all spelled fine there. Anyway I don't see it has something to do with properties file itself - `@ConfigurationProperties` bean class name is not related to the properties file contents...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-security`, Spring Boot will be auto-configuring its own `SecurityProperties` bean that's also annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`. Unfortunately this bean will have the same name as your bean as the class names (ignoring the package) are the same. This name clash means that Spring Boot's been will be overriding your security properties bean. You should see a warning message to that effect logged during startup.

As you have observed, changing the name of your bean so that there's no longer a name clash will solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, I've finally come to the same decision... But from my perspective Spring might have been more verbose on that - you can't learn by heart all its built-in beans to avoid situations like that. On the other hand it might be a good idea to explicitly give your beans unique names that surely can't collide with Spring's. Just in case.